# how to avoid repeating answers in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

Here is My Question :

```
?- rule7(X,Y,t3).

X = s10,
Y = s11 ;
X = s12,
Y = s10 ;
X = s12,
Y = s10 ;
X = s12,
Y = s11 ;
X = s12,
Y = s11 ;
X = s12,
Y = s13 ;
X = s12,
Y = s13 .....
```

It will repeat it lot of times. How can I reduce these repeatings...

The Code :

```erlang
rule7(X,Y,T) :-
  course(C,X),
  course(C1,Y),
  course_lec(C1,T),
  course_lec(C,T),
  copy_rec(Y,X).
```

Comment: Can you supply the code for **course**, **course_lect** and **copy_rec** ?

The more complete the question the easier it is to solve it.

Comment: for example : 
course(c1,s1).
course(c1,s2).
..etc

course_lec(c1,t1).
course_lec(c2,t1).
..etc 

copy_rec(Y,X):- copy_stu(Y,X).
copy_rec(Y,X):-copy_stu(Y,Z),copy_rec(Z,X).

Comment: `setof(t, rule7(X,Y,t3), _).`

Comment: But maybe `copy_rec/2` does not terminate. You need to show the entire code

Comment: Please put any code updates/additions in your question (use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44520050/edit)) and not in comments, where they're hard to find and read. How is `copy_stu/2` defined? What does `rule7/3` mean (what does it do, in plain language)? Sometimes getting rid of duplicates is about defining the rule more precisely.

Comment: thank you @false working fine